# Heroku PHP Builpack logging

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails application running on heroku with a php buildpack, but I can't get the php logs, I created a custom logging file on `log/custom.php`, does anyone can suggest me a solution to read the log/custom.php? according to heroku I must use a log addon but I couldn't found any good information about how to do this with a buildpack.

Comment: Can you run `$  heroku buildpacks` and say what it returns ?

Comment: Hello @ShyamBhimani   `=== app-name Buildpack URLs
1. heroku/php
2. heroku/ruby`